# Twig table not formatting correctly

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a feeling I am missing something silly here.  I an rendering the following

```
<div class="availability_table_container">
    <table class="availability_table">
        {% for pseudo in alert.getPseudos %}
            {% for flight in alert.getFlightNumbers %}
                <tr>
                    <th class='pseudo-header'>{{ flight.getFlightNumber }}</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {% for date in alert.getAvailability %}
                        {{ date.getLastUpdated|date('d M Y H:00') }}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
```

To me, there is nothing that stands out wrong there.  However, I noticed my dates seemed to be placed in the middle of nowhere.  So I looked at the source and I get

```
<div class="availability_table_container">
    26 Feb 2015 12:00 26 Feb 2015 12:00 26 Feb 2015 13:00 26 Feb 2015 13:00
    <table class="availability_table">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="pseudo-header">VS7</th>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

So it has placed the dates outside of the table, and my table rows where the date should be is empty.  Even if I remove the foreach within this tr and just output TEST instead, the situation is still the same.

So why would it be placing any code here outside of the table?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `td` inside the `tr`

```
            <tr>
                {% for date in alert.getAvailability %}
                   <td> {{ date.getLastUpdated|date('d M Y H:00') }}  </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
```

Or something else like (it depends on what you exactly want ):

```
             <tr>
                <td>
                {% for date in alert.getAvailability %}
                   {{ date.getLastUpdated|date('d M Y H:00') }} 
                {% endfor %}
                 </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: I knew it was something stupid, lol.  I spent so long concentrating on table row that I forgot about table data.